# Type.IsSubclassOf in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

So I am porting library from .NET 4.5.1 to UWP.

In library we were using methods from Type class, particularly **Type.IsSubclassOf**. But in UWP I cannot find any equivalent method.

Is there a way how can I found if some class is subclass of some other class in UWP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Part of the `Type` logic is moved to `TypeInfo`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)) in Windows Runtime.

```
using System.Reflection;

...

bool isSubClassOf = typeof (Dog).GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof (Animal));
```